# Is it possible to send facebook-messages to someone who uses my facebook-application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

And in that case what's the name of the permission/method/function etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe user-to-user is possible (At least I have seen for chat in OmgPop)
For application to user,
You can only read for now using the `/inbox` endpoint.
You will need the `read_mailbox` permission.

You can read more from the [2009 post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/291).

> While we currently don't allow applications to send messages through this API, we're always thinking about new functionality to offer through Facebook Platform.